# Clang/LD function demangling?

Tags: ios, linker, clang, ld, name-mangling

I have two working compilers, `clang` on a `Mac`, which can target `iPhone`, and `clang` on an `iPhone`, which also targets `iPhone`. Normally both work great, generating binaries and libraries. Libraries produced on the `Mac` can be linked on the `iPhone`. But now I face a strange issue: a **library is not linking** while trying to link on iPhone against a library created on the Mac.

```
Undefined symbols:
  "__Z7JS_Initji", referenced from:
      _main in test-CgDtHX.o
```

This is a call to JS_Init, which is defined as a macro which expands differently.

`iphone-clang` will expand it as:

```
extern JSRuntime * JS_Init(uint32_t maxbytes, int);
```

`mac-clang` will expand as:

```
extern JSRuntime * JS_Init(uint32_t maxbytes, JSUseHelperThreads useHelperThreads);
```

I am not sure **if the macro expansion is the reason for the linking failure**.

Ok, now my question, what exactly `ji` and `Z7` mean in  `__Z7JS_Initji`? Where can I find the table that will show me the correspondence between `argument types` and those `mangling ids`? This must be `ld` docs, but I am unable to find it. Mostly because I do not know good query words for this.

Comment: Which linker do you use under iOS, btw ?

Comment: I think it was the one that comes with Cydia binutils.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a long reference on how (amongst other things) function name mangling works in GCC/Clang:

http://mentorembedded.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html#mangling

In section 5.1.5 Type Encodings, you'll see that the "ji" stands for "unsigned int" and "int".

_Z at the the start is from section 5.1.2 (prefix for all function names), the "7" is the length of the name "JS_Init".

Hope that helps!

Comment: I think now that should be https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html#mangling ?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will help.

Searching for mangle in the XCode 4.6 docset, I found

LINKER_DISPLAYS_MANGLED_NAMES (Display Mangled Names)
Description:
Boolean value. Specifies whether the linker displays mangled names for C++ symbols. This information can help in diagnosing C++ linking problems.
Values:
YES: The linker displays mangled names for C++ symbols (ld --no-demangle).
NO: The linker does not display mangled names for C++ symbols.
Default value:
NO

So I can't tell you what ji and Z7 mean, but this might help you improve your linker messages.

Hope that helps